# Dojo build profile.layers vs. profile.dependencies.layers?

Tags: dojo, build-process, dojo-build

Wow, this is totally confusing and the dojo 1.8 documentation seems a complete clusterf**k around build layers. Anybody have a clue what's going on there?

In the build script example profiles, the example amd.profile.js has **profile.layers["dojo/dojo"]** and the [tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/build/) follows this same syntax.

Besides the tutorial, in the 1.8 [build documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/) there is no mention of this kind of structure, but of **profile.dependencies.layers[n]**.

The documentation also references non-AMD syntax and, just to add another "layer" of confusion, there's also a **profile.dependencies.layers[n].dependencies**.

Which should I be using? Is this actually documented anywhere with any consistency or clarity?

Answer (score 3):

I have learned that the Dojo 1.8 Reference Guide contains obsolete information regarding build profiles, but that the Dojo 1.8 Build tutorial is current:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/build/

That tutorial recommends this blog post for more information about layers and build optimization: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/06/11/dgrid-and-dojo-nano-build/